# File field is not being included in @Body decorator in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to build a simple route where the user will post few text data along with a file. Let's say a task where the properties will be title, description, and file. I have created a DTO for this as follows:-

```
export class CreateTaskDto {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  file: any
}
```

And here is the `storage.config.ts`

```
export const storage = diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads",
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, generateFilename(file));
  }
});

function generateFilename(file) {
  const filename = file.originalname
  const ext = filename.split(".").pop()
  return `${Date.now()}_${filename}`;
}
```

The `tasks.controller.ts`

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors( FileInterceptor( "file", { storage }))
async createNewTask(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() dto: CreateTaskDto) {
  /*
   here is the dto I received:
   {
      "title": "Task Title",
      "description": "Task Description"
   }

   You can see that the file field is not being added to the dto
   */
}
```

The `file` field data is not included in the `@Body` decorator variable `dto`. I know I can access the file data via the `file` variable but is there any way to instruct nest to include the file value into the @Body decorator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `multer` works, it takes the uploaded files and attaches them to `req.file` or `req.files` depending on if one or many were sent. You could create a [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) to merge the `req.body` and `req.file` together if you wanted, but generally this isn't something Nest does, but the underlying package itself.