# in nestjs how to get dto list that include file?

Tags: nestjs

i want to get dtos that includes file in nestjs.
but i can't find how i get this json array in nestjs.

ex) json array

```
[
  {brand : "A", file : file},
  {brand : "B", file : file}
]
```

dto:

```
export class fileDto {
  brand: string;
  file: File;
}
```

i saw similar question.
[File field is not being included in @Body decorator in NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389414/file-field-is-not-being-included-in-body-decorator-in-nestjs)

is there any way to get this array in nestjs ?